# .htaccess - Redirects are not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

There's a secure page in public_html profile.php which checks whether the user is logged in. It redirects to login.php when not logged in. It works when I try to access http://my-domain.com/profile but not when http://my-domain.com/profile/ (slash at the end)

here my .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

index.php

```
<?php

    $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $chunks = explode("/", $path);

    //print_r($chunks);


    if($chunks[1] == "profile") {

        if($chunks[2] != "") {
            $profile_id = $chunks[2];
            require_once("profile.php");        
        } else {
            require_once("profile.php");        
        }

    }
?>
```

profile.php

```
<?php

    require_once("../includes/initialize.php");

if(!$session->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect_to("login.php");
    }

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $profile_id = $_GET['id'];
    }

    echo "This is the profile page of ID: ".$profile_id;

?>
```

Comment: Where is `$_GET['id']` coming from?

Comment: if some user directly comes like profile.php?id=1 then it can access the id from GET and if he comes like profile/1/ then on the index.php im setting the profile_id.

Comment: So what problem happens when somebody opens `http://my-domain.com/profile/` and is `/profile/` a real directory?

Comment: not a real directory.

Comment: Still you didn't respond to the first part of question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because with the trailing slash it is a directory and it matches the `-d` test.

I use this bit to make sure I never have a trailing slash

```
## Redirect to remove trailing slashes on extensionless URL requests 
# If requested URL ending with slash does not resolve to an existing directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Externally redirect to remove trailing slash 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This redirects to logout and then to login.php but nothing comes with it but a blank page.

this works http://mysite.in/login but now not this http://mysite.in/login.php

Comment: I cant see real quick why not. I assume you have error_reporting on

Comment: Thanks it got resolved. This is the first day of my Clean URLing.

Comment: Haha, can be a pain in the ass ;) If you made some significant change, font forget to add it to your topic :) For others.